# Duplicate URL's in Joomla

Tags: url, joomla, duplicates

I have a lot of duplicate content in joomla caused by the presence of /m/ in some pages eg 
https://astarmathsandphysics.com/m/gcse-physics-notes/852-the-endoscope.html
https://astarmathsandphysics.com/gcse-physics-notes/852-the-endoscope.html
I want to remove the supserfluous /m/ by redirecting any url with this in to the url without.
How do I don this in .htaccess?
Nothing I have seen on the internet answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by putting this is .htaccess

RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]